# DocuSign API: Is it possible to filter envelopes by the value a document field?

Tags: rest, docusignapi, envelope

Assuming I have a field with label FOO in all the envelopes sent, how do I filter the envelopes where the value of FOO is 123456?
I tried setting the search_text parameter with 123456 but it doesn't work.

This is the request I tried to use:

`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/reste_idreste/envelopes?from_date=2021-02-01&search_text=123456`

Comment: it can filter the value of the fields, but I don't think it can do labels. I'm not clear if 123456 is a text in a text field or a label presented to the user (static). I think it can filter custom fields, text fields and values of other tabs, but I don't think it can do labels.

Comment: You can search for Envelope Custom Fields, but you can't search for Tabs. Which type of field are you looking for?

Comment: @Drew I'm looking for a text field in Tab. If I can't search by Tab, do I need to download the form data of each envelope and filter the results? Do you know if there is a way to get the form data in the envelope listStatusChanges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not currently a way to search Tabs/Form Data via the API. We do have long term plans in this area, but nothing firm yet. I would pass this request along to your account team to let them know you are interested in learning more about that functionality as it develops.

The `ListStatusChanges` call doesn't allow you to pull form data in bulk. You'd need to make one `GetEnvelope` call per envelope with `include=recipients,tabs` to pull form data and parse through it yourself.

If this is something you are looking at building out, you could use populate a local database using the GetEnvelope results, and then use DocuSign Connect to automatically pass information about new envelopes moving forward.

It is possible to search for values of Envelope Custom Fields. Moving forward, if your application can populate an ECF, you can then search for that to find specific envelopes.